# WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 107, so returning the closest version found: 106

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

I have Google Chrome version 107.0.5304.6, and I'm using WebDriverManager to get the same chromeDriver version. I download Google Chrome version 106 and run my tests and this issue didn't happen, but my Google Chrome updates automatically from version 106 to 107 and the warning happens again.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and resolved using the following steps:

Step1: Add the following devtools dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v88</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-beta-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Step2: change v88 to the Chrome Version you have on your machine. e.g., v106 or v107

Step3: change the beta version to the latest one. e.g., 4.0.0-beta-1 to 4.5.3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which google version do you have and how did you import this dependency? I tried to use this dependency as you explained, but it is not working.                                                                            
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v106</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1):

As of [Selenium CHANGELOG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) CDP version 107 is supported starting selenium v4.6.0

you just need to update selenium java version to 4.6.0 or later

```
<properties>
    <selenium.version>4.6.0</selenium.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

just download the chrome driver version 107 and update in your dependency folder

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=107.0.5304.62/
this resolves the issue